# read the contents of a list of files to another list in python

Tags: python

So I have a directory with several files nested inside. If I use `os.listdir` that will place the contents of the directory into a list, which in my case gives me a list of 20 subdirectories. I want to get the contents of those 20 subdirectories in a new list, but I know I can't use `os.listdir` again because I keep getting errors.

```
myList = os.listdir(myPath)
for files in myList:
   listfiles = os.listdir(files)
```

I'm not sure what to do, or if there is another `os` function I should be using.

Answer (score 0):

Below code gives all files in given directory, recursively.

```
listfiles = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        listfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

If given path isn't absolute, try below code to get absolute path:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        listfiles.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file)))
```

Or if you need just file names

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        listfiles.append(file)
```